# open a simple pop up window with my string contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jquery getJSON method to get the two strings from java servlet. one string contains the type of data like simple string, XML and HTML and another string contains data. I need to open a popup window with different size based on contents.

Below the code used to get the strings.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX calls using Jquery in Servlet</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>       

        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function() {                        

                $('#submit').click(function(event) {  

                    var applid=$('#applicationid').val();
                    var applname=$('#appname').val();

                 $.getJSON('ActionServlet',
                         {
                     appid:applid,
                     appname:applname
                     },function(data) { 
                        var errortype = data.errortype;
                        var errorMsg = data.errorMsg;                            
                     }); 
                }); 
            });

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">

<h1>AJAX Demo using Jquery in JSP and Servlet</h1>

Enter your Name:

<input type="text" id="applicationid"/>
<input type="text" id="appname"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Ajax Submit"/>

<br/>
<div id="hello" title="Hello  World!"></div> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. In general you have the `window.open()` and `window.alert()` functions for opening different popups.

Comment: yes.. I included window.open with document.write(errorMsg) and it pen simple string and HTML content without any issues, but the variable contains XML the whole XML is not shown in the pop up window. is there any way to include XML data in the body of pop up window.

Comment: Do you want to see the XML with the tags, instead of parsing it? In this case, you need to `escape()` your XML.

Comment: Thanks..escape() is working, but it display as raw xml like "%3Csoapenv%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3Asoapenv%3D%22http%". I think i need to send without conversion from servlet, or is there any way to do in javascript?

Comment: You are right. `escape()` is not the right function. I added an answer below.

Comment: There's [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com) for that; what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks...I have opened the XML as text by providing myWindow.document.open("text/plain"). But still is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can user fancybox. It gives options for opening the passed html string [check here](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window you can use the window.open() function.

To display the XML as raw text, you need to escape the special characters.
Javascript does not have builtin function for it (like htmlentities() in php).

You can try the following code:

```
function htmlentities(str)
{
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```